# All-in-one PHP bundle for Ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu

I need to deploy Zend Framework app on Ubuntu.
I've downloaded Ubuntu desktop, installed using apt-get apache+php+mysql,
but PHP turned out to be not the latest 5.3, but 5.2.1 and even 
mysql extension is missing.

I understand I can get somewhere a fresh php installation, get dependent libs (like curl or libxml2) compile them one by one and then I get full-features latest PHP bundle.

But is there anywhere already full PHP bundle with latest version and all libs to get
ZF app running very quickly?

Comment: why did you install ubuntu desktop instead of the server version?

Comment: I was going to rely on desktop UI for basic tasks in the beginning.  Is that all I need to do, change to Server version?

Comment: no, it doesnt resolve the question, i was just curios ;)

Answer (score 2):

One of the downsides of package management is that you're at the mercy of the package maintainers. [Ubuntu has opted not to update to PHP 5.3 in this version](http://www.brandonsavage.net/php-5-3-not-in-next-version-of-ubuntu/), so you'll have to either wait until 2010 for it or compile PHP yourself.

Comment: +1 If you going to make the jump to Ubuntu, then it will be worth while to learn to compile PHP as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the PHP extensions that arent in a default source build directly from PHP are in seperate apt packages. If you do a search for PHP5 in you package manager youll see packages like:

```
PHP5
PHP5-Mysql
PHP5-cli
PHP5-SQLite
```

etc..

Im going to assume that there are also packages specifically for php 5.3 - most likely labeled as `php53-*` or something similar. You may need to adda repo for this as im not sure its in the crore repos.

Anyhow you need to isntall all these packages that you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues getting the latest PHP on my CentOS server.  I installed [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/products/server-ce/downloads), which sets up it's own Apache/PHP5.3 stack in /usr/local/zend.  And here's a [Getting Started article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4295).

It's a full PHP bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you need other packages for Ubuntu, check the ubuntu repository for PHP5 at http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/